# What Encryption Methods do sites like Paypal, Ebay, and Amazon use?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords

Adobe's recent leaking of 150 million credit card numbers is unforgivable considering they used encryption that will be cracked in no time. Fortunately, I only had an Adobe forum account with zero real info stored.

I was googling and trying to find out what ebay, paypal, and amazon use. **Are they using salted hashes?** These are the main places I actually store financial info. **How secure are they?** I use LastPass etc and keep my accounts as secure as possible. So if something goes wrong, it's always on the company's end. Most sites I simply do not store my cards at all and enter the info when I make a rare purchase. Although, I've heard some websites store your info  anyway, even if you tell it not to on your profile settings. ugh...

Any big name website storing credit card info should be using the best encryption possible. Who hires these code monkey clowns?

Comment: We cannot answer these questions—only the companies can. This isn't about computer hardware or software, only internal practices you are probably not going to find out easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe was using a reversible encryption (and weak encryption at that) for storing their passwords, and as such were not using a well crafted hash.

unfortunately you will never know what any given company uses in its back-end until it has been hacked and the company is forced to make a statement.

Adobe's issue is that it has been around too long, and was written by standards more acceptable at the end of the last century than today.

Comment: If the passwords were stored using reversible encryption, Adobe *could* have upgraded their password storage without forcing users to reset their passwords.

Comment: good point. too bad they didn't